# Show $66!\equiv 68 \pmod{71}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question asked to show $66!\equiv 68 \pmod{71}$. I start with using Wilson Theorem,I get $70!\equiv -1\pmod{71}$, next I try to write $70!=70*69*68*67*66!\equiv (-1)*(-2)*(-3)*(-4)*66! \equiv24\pmod{71}$. Can anyone give some hint? Or point out where I am wrong?

Comment: Note that $71$ is prime, so there exists a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{F}_{71}$ for each of those.  For example, $(2)^{-1} = 36$ since $2\cdot 36 \equiv 72\equiv 1\pmod{71}$.  So, $(-2)^{-1}=35$.  What is the multiplicative inverse of $-1$?  Of $-3$? Of $-4$?  What is $70!\cdot (-1)^{-1}\cdot (-2)^{-1}\cdots (-4)^{-1} \pmod {71}$?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  You have $$70! \equiv 70 \cdot 69 \cdot 68 \cdot 67 \cdot 66! \equiv -1 \cdot -2 \cdot -3 \cdot -4 \cdot 66! \equiv 24 \cdot 66! \mod{71}$$ (in your calculation, you left out the 66! in the last step).  Now, as you noted, by Wilson's theorem, the left side $70!  \equiv -1 \mod{71}$, so we have $$-1 \equiv 24 \cdot 66! \mod{71}.$$  Therefore, to prove the given claim, we must verify that $$-1 \equiv 24 \cdot 68 \mod{71}$$ which is a straightforward calculation.  Once we verify that, we have $24 \cdot 66! \equiv 24 \cdot 68 \mod{71}$, and use the fact that 24 is relatively prime to 71 to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

You should end up with 
$$70!\equiv (-1)(-2)(-3)(-4)\times66!\,(\text{mod 71})\equiv -1\,(\text{mod 71})$$

Hence you want to find a number $0\leq n \leq 70$ such that
$$24n\equiv 70\,(\text {mod 71})$$

Comment: To do this note you can divide by $2$ modulo $71$ so this becomes $12n\equiv 35\equiv -36$. Then you can divide by $12$ to get $n\equiv -3\equiv 68$.